# won't show me the data that i pass to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

here is my code for first activity:

```
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(Categories.this, Books.class);
final String selectedCategory = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
i.putExtra("category", selectedCategory);
startActivity(i);
}
```

and here is for my second activity:

```
Intent passedCategory =getIntent();
String vCategory = passedCategory.getStringExtra("category");
TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CategoryPass);
v.setText(vCategory);
```

`CategoryPass` -- id of `TextView` in XML file

and when i run this it wont show me anything in the `TextView`, am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Check that selectedCategory isn't null

Comment: checked - it is null.... why? :/

Comment: BEcause no item is selected.  Use parent.getItemAtPosition(position) instead.

Comment: now i have a FATAL EXCEPTION... java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String...